# R programming XML: accessing duplicate node

Tags: xml, r, nodes

I would like to access a node which has been duplicated in an xml file
Here is part of the file i am using

```
</tig>
<aug>
 <au>Lee, Kuei-Chiu</au>
 <au>Chang, Yu-Hui</au>
</aug>
```

When i used the following code i can only access the first name

```
    authors=xmlSApply(r,function(x)
  xmlValue(x[['header']][['controlInfo']][['artinfo']][['aug']][['au']]))
```

Is there a way to index the second 'au' part of this node(i.e Chang, Yu-Hui) ?

Many thanks

Barry

Answer (score 1):

Using an [xpath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) (especially section 2.5 for starters) is a very flexible way to index into an xml document, something like

```
r[["//au[2]"]]
```